# Input from textbox in datagrid stack panel WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, stackpanel

How can I get input in code behind from textbox tbUser?
I need that input to work with in code behind and i get the error that **`tbUser` doesn't exist**.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding User Name}" Width="130" MinWidth="130" MaxWidth="150"> 
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="1"
                    Name="tbUser" Width="117" MinWidth="117" MaxWidth="147"/>
                <TextBlock Text="User Name" Margin="1" FontWeight="DemiBold"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate` to `DataGridTextColumn.Header`, because you use this template for only this column, and you don't overide `ControlTemplate`.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UserName}" Width="130" MinWidth="130" MaxWidth="150">
        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="1" Name="tbUser" Width="117" MinWidth="117" MaxWidth="147"/>
                <TextBlock Text="User Name" Margin="1" FontWeight="DemiBold"
            TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

There is a binding error `Binding="{Binding User Name}"`. Do you mean `Binding="{Binding UserName}"` (no space)?

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. No error, i bind from SQL table, and User Name is the name of the column.. with space in it :)

Comment: Right. Glad it help you :)